# Matching sequence of two dataframes with similar string parttern keeping index and sequence

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have two dataframes df and df1. where I have to match sequence or strings and getting the only matching string sequence with index number of df as output.

df

```
idx id_0 user string
0 008457 02 hello
1 990037 05 I 
2 774426 10 am
3 564389 08 sleeping
4 009124 17 today
5 000029 13 is
6 548751 21 a
7 479903 19 bright
8 897054 08 sunny
9 336588 7 day
10 294260 16 today 
11 908751 29 is 
12 558902 81 rainy
13 097856 19 with
14 110044 24 cold
15 775098 16 today 
16 665490 02 is
17 887099 07 sunday 
18 389011 18 ahhh
19 675510 11 weekend
```

df1

```
idx string
0 today
1 is
2 a
3 bright
4 sunny
5 day
```

output:

```
idx id_0 user string
4 009124 17 today
5 000029 13 is
6 548751 21 a
7 479903 19 bright
8 897054 08 sunny
9 336588 7 day
```

I tried with several methods pd.merge, pd.concat, pd.join, also with isin, but, I get the wrong index number.

e.g.,

```
out = df1[df1['string'].isin(df.index().['string'])]
```

Comment: "I tried with several methods pd.merge, pd.concat, pd.join, also with isin, but, I get the wrong index number." --- please include these tries in your question

Comment: I see some words in `df` are repeated, how do you know which index / user to keep? It seems like you are just keeping the first

Comment: It might be more easy for others to answer your question, if you included a copy-pastable  piece of code that can create your input dataframe.

Comment: @np8 `df = pd.read_clipboard()` works well on these examples

Comment: @Dan I have to keep the index of df not the small dataset df1

Comment: @Dan that's an useful tip! Thanks!

Comment: @ML85 the word `is` has 3 different indices in `df` - how are you choosing which to keep?

Comment: btw something to get you started: `pd.merge(df, df1, on="string").groupby("idx_y").min().set_index("idx_x")`

Comment: @Dan I want idx sequence only. regardless of other columns. but the sequence of string should not get disturbed. this is what  I want. the middle two columns here can be ignored.

Comment: I'll try one last time, for the word `"is"` in `df1` how did you choose an `idx` of `5` over `11` or `16`?

Comment: @Dan. KeyError: 'idx_y' can you guide how to get / handle it?

Comment: maybe by spacy / or scikit any solution?

Comment: @Dan you are right. this is the thing, as the strings have repeated items. or maybe groups or words with close clustering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible way to do that is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [0, "008457", "02", "hello"],
    [1, "990037", "05", "I"],
    [2, "774426", "10", "am"],
    [3, "564389", "08", "sleeping"],
    [4, "009124", "17", "today"],
    [5, "000029", "13", "is"],
    [6, "548751", "21", "a"],
    [7, "479903", "19", "bright"],
    [8, "897054", "08", "sunny"],
    [9, "336588", "7", "day"],
    [10, "294260", "16", "today"],
    [11, "908751", "29", "is"],
    [12, "558902", "81", "rainy"],
    [13, "097856", "19", "with"],
    [14, "110044", "24", "cold"],
    [15, "775098", "16", "today"],
    [16, "665490", "02", "is"],
    [17, "887099", "07", "sunday"],
    [18, "389011", "18", "ahhh"],
    [19, "675510", "11", "weekend"]
],
columns=["idx", "id_0", "user", "string"]
)
df = df.set_index('idx')

df1 = pd.DataFrame([
[0, "today"],
[1, "is"],
[2, "a"],
[3, "bright"],
[4, "sunny"],
[5, "day"]
],
columns=["idx", "string"]
)


matching_indices = []
for i in range(len(df)-len(df1)+1):
    if (df.string.iloc[i:i+len(df1)].values == df1.string.values).all():
        matching_indices += list(range(i,i+len(df1)))

df.iloc[matching_indices]
```

With output:

```
    id_0    user    string
idx         
4   009124  17  today
5   000029  13  is
6   548751  21  a
7   479903  19  bright
8   897054  08  sunny
9   336588  7   day
```

The above code will return all the matching subsequences with their correct indices, not only the first occurrence.

If you wish to return only the first occurrence you can break the loop the first time a match is identified, like below:

```
matching_indices = []
for i in range(len(df)-len(df1)+1):
    if (df.string.iloc[i:i+len(df1)].values == df1.string.values).all():
        matching_indices += list(range(i,i+len(df1)))
        break

df.iloc[matching_indices]
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert df1.strings to list, and compare to df with apply and a lambda function:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [0, "008457", "02", "hello"],
    [1, "990037", "05", "I"],
    [2, "774426", "10", "am"],
    [3, "564389", "08", "sleeping"],
    [4, "009124", "17", "today"],
    [5, "000029", "13", "is"],
    [6, "548751", "21", "a"],
    [7, "479903", "19", "bright"],
    [8, "897054", "08", "sunny"],
    [9, "336588", "7", "day"],
    [10, "294260", "16", "today"],
    [11, "908751", "29", "is"],
    [12, "558902", "81", "rainy"],
    [13, "097856", "19", "with"],
    [14, "110044", "24", "cold"],
    [15, "775098", "16", "today"],
    [16, "665490", "02", "is"],
    [17, "887099", "07", "sunday"],
    [18, "389011", "18", "ahhh"],
    [19, "675510", "11", "weekend"]
],
columns=["idx", "id_0", "user", "string"]
)

df1 = pd.DataFrame([
[0, "today"],
[1, "is"],
[2, "a"],
[3, "bright"],
[4, "sunny"],
[5, "day"]
],
columns=["idx", "string"]
)

string_list = df1.string.tolist()
filt = df['string'].apply(lambda x: any([k in x for k in string_list]))
print(df[filt])
```

Returning:

```
    idx    id_0 user  string
2     2  774426   10      am
4     4  009124   17   today
5     5  000029   13      is
6     6  548751   21       a
7     7  479903   19  bright
8     8  897054   08   sunny
9     9  336588    7     day
10   10  294260   16   today
11   11  908751   29      is
12   12  558902   81   rainy
15   15  775098   16   today
16   16  665490   02      is
17   17  887099   07  sunday
18   18  389011   18    ahhh
```

Comment: TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not float throwing this error. But this return is more than the matching item sequence as well.